# Why does my deepface installation not work?

Tags: python, deepface

I'm not sure why my installation of python library "deepface" isn't working.

I have tried running the command

```
pip install deepface
```

and

```
git clone https://github.com/serengil/deepface.git
cd deepface
pip install -e .
```

However, despite having confirmation that deepface has been installed Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize it as a libary.

[image]

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: VS isn't vscode. how many pythons do you have? virtual environments?

Comment: You must have two (or more) separate installations of Python on your computer.  `pip` installed the module for one version, but you're using a different version to run the code.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show deepface` (just the Location part of the output), and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon
 `PS C:\Users\rabbi\Desktop\FacialRecog> pip show deepface
Name: deepface
Version: 0.0.79
Summary: A Lightweight Face Recognition and Facial Attribute Analysis Framework (Age, Gender, Emotion, Race) for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/serengil/deepface
Author: Sefik Ilkin Serengil
Author-email: serengil@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\rabbi\scoop\persist\python\lib\site-packages
Requires: fire, Flask, gdown, gunicorn, keras, mtcnn, numpy, opencv-python, pandas, Pillow, retina-face, tensorflow, tqdm
Required-by:`

Comment: @JohnGordon I re-opened VSCode and now it no longer shows the "Import deepface could not be resolved message". However when I tried to run the program, I received this message instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rabbi\Desktop\FacialRecog\recog.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from deepface import DeepFace
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepFace' from 'deepface' (unknown location)
PS C:\Users\rabbi\Desktop\FacialRecog>

Comment: You haven't shown the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon ['c:\\Users\\rabbi\\Desktop\\FacialRecog', 'C:\\Users\\rabbi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\rabbi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\rabbi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\rabbi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38', 'C:\\Users\\rabbi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Well, that is the problem.  As I thought, you have two different python installations.  Pip is using `c:\users\rabbi\scoop\persist\python`, but your code is using `C:\Users\rabbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`.

Comment: You need to pick which installation of Python you want to use, and make sure all the tools agree on that version.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your help. Not sure how I managed to install two pythons